# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' Dont understand

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
yen = 0.0067
bsp = 1.35
usd = 0.65
ero = 0.85

if choice == "2":
    Current_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
    if Current_Currency == "yen":
        amount = input("Type amount you wish to exchange")
        Future_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange into: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
        New_Amount = Future_Currency * amount
```

I have to build this and apparently I need a float through research but I dont have a clue on how to implement it.

Comment: Is this Python 2? What did you enter on the prompt?

Comment: `Current_Currency` will not be a string, it will be the value of the `yen` variable. So comparing it to the string `"yen"` will not be true

Comment: so how would i fix it sorry im new to all this

Comment: @JoshG79: whether or not `input` evaluates depends on whether the OP is using Python 2 or 3.  If the error message is being generated by the `New_Amount` line, then the branch must have been taken, in which case `Current_Currency` *is* a string, the OP is using Python 3 [or typed `"yen"`, I guess], and the problem is that we're trying to multiply two strings, which would indeed generate this error message.  @MartijnPieters asked exactly the two questions that matter.

Comment: This has to be Python 3, I very much doubt that user2687255 would have typed `'yen'` and `"2342342"` in the prompt.

Comment: However the code looks as if it is taken from an illconceived python 2 tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are confusing variable names with variables. Because the currency type you get from the user is a string, it can't be used to reference variables unless you call eval on it.

```
new_amount = eval(future_currency) * amount
```

The downside of this is that using `eval` gives the user a possible way to affect your code. Instead, you can use a dictionary. Dictionaries map strings to values, and so you can take your variable declarations:

```
yen = 0.0067
bsp = 1.35
usd = 0.65
ero = 0.85
```

And turn them into a dictionary:

```
currencies = {'yen': 0.0067, 'bsp': 1.35, 'usd': 0.65, 'ero': 0.85}
```

Using this, you can find the value you are looking for in the dictionary. Don't forget to handle incorrect user input properly!

```
currencies = {'yen': 0.0067, 'bsp': 1.35, 'usd': 0.65, 'ero': 0.85}

current_currency = raw_input()
future_currency = raw_input()
amount = int(raw_input())
// Check for errors in input here
new_amount = amount * currencies[future_currency] / currencies[current_currency]
```

Comment: replace `input` with `raw_input` (then do an `int` on `amount`), and this gets +1 from me. `input` does an `eval`, so you would need to specify literally `"yen"` (including the quotes), which also doesn't follow your sage advice to avoid using `eval` at all due to security concerns

Comment: ok i understood very little but thank will try to imperment second option due to security reasons

Comment: user runs this on python 3, and maybe the (ill-conceived) example was written for python 2.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Current_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
```

will throw an error if an unknown variable is entered, and `Current_Currency` will be set to the value of the variable name provided by the user, so the line

```
if Current_Currency == "yen":
```

isn't really needed.

```
yen = 0.0067
bsp = 1.35
usd = 0.65
ero = 0.85

Current_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
amount = input("Type amount you wish to exchange")
Future_Currency = input("What currency do you want to exchange into: Japenese Yen if so please type yen // British Sterling Pound please type bsp // US Dollers please Type usd // Euro please type ero.")
New_Amount =  Current_Currency / Future_Currency * amount
```

Comment: sorry mate dosent work comes up with this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/James/Downloads/Currency_Coverter_v1-4.py", line 30, in <module>
    New_Amount = Future_Currency / Current_Currency * amount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: What you enter gets eval'd directly, so if you enter "yen" with the quotes, Current_Currency will be "yen", but if you enter yen without the quotes, Current_Currency will be 0.0067.  Unless, of course, python behaves differently on your system than mine.

Comment: think it does and what is eval hear it all the time but dont understand

Comment: Here eval means the interpreter is evaluating the text that was input as python code.  Effectively, you are allowing the user to insert arbitrary code into your running script at that point.  For example, if instead of selecting a currency, the user entered python code to delete your home directory, your script would do just that, and return the result in Current_Currency

Comment: @AnttiHaapala informs me that `input` does not evaluate anything as of Python 3, so my previous comment could be entirely irrelevant if you are using 3+